# Help with this Linq query (many-to-many join)

Tags: c#, linq

I have three domain objects:

Child, Classroom and ChildClassroom. Here are lists of each:

```
var childrens = new List<Child>() {
    new Child() { ChildId = 1, FirstName = "Chris" },
    new Child() { ChildId = 2, FirstName = "Jenny" },
    new Child() { ChildId = 3, FirstName = "Dave"  },
};

var classrooms = new List<Classroom>() {
   new Classroom() { ClassroomId = 1, FullName = "Kindergarten" },
   new Classroom() { ClassroomId = 2, FullName = "Elementary"   },
   new Classroom() { ClassroomId = 3, FullName = "Secondary"    },
};

var childclassrooms = new List<ChildClassroom>() {
   new ChildClassroom() { ClassroomId = 1, ChildId = 1 },
   new ChildClassroom() { ClassroomId = 2, ChildId = 1 },
   new ChildClassroom() { ClassroomId = 3, ChildId = 2 },
};
```

What I want is:

```
 var childClassroomRelationships = new object[] {
     new {
         childid = 1,
         classrooms = new object[] {
            new { classroomId = 1, occupied = true  },
            new { classroomId = 2, occupied = true  },
            new { classroomId = 3, occupied = false }
     },
     ...
 };
```

What's the way to go about this in Linq?

Comment: I'd start with formatting it better.

Comment: If you create the array without using type inferrence (`new []{...}`) you can then access the members of the anonymous type: `childClassroomRelationships[0].childid`. If you create it as `new object[]` you won't be able to do much with the anonymous type without some wizardry.

Comment: @Yuriy- Done. Now you should be able to answer.

Comment: @Martinho, I was just sketching out my expected result. In all likelihood it will be a real, persistent class when I'm finished. Feel free to post your response as an anonymous type or however's most convenient.

Comment: Where does `occupied` come from? And from your data it doesn't look like classroom 3 should be in the list.

Comment: @Adam- it denotes that that classroom is occupied by the parent child. I'm looking for every classroom to be in the list, with a flag for whether or not that child is in that classroom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var kidsInClass = (
    from kid in childrens
    from c in classrooms
    select new {
        ChildID = kid.ChildId,
        classrooms = (
            from cc in childclassrooms
            select new {
                ClassroomID = c.ClassroomId,
                Occupied = cc.ChildId == kid.ChildId
            }).ToArray()
    }).ToArray();
```

Comment: @casperOne I don't think that format edit was called for, but maybe thats just me.

Comment: @Yuriy: Thanks for all your help with this question.

Comment: @Yuriy Faktorovich: Are your referring to this answer, or to your question? Either way, both are in need of formatting, as the horizontal scrollbars as well as the lack of readability are signs of very, very poor formatting.

Comment: @casperOne I was referring to your edit. I agree horizontal scrollbars are bad. But thats dependent on the width of the browser. It looks like msarchet used settings from Resharper or similar tools for his formatting, and you used VS. I'll see if I can fix it. I've also fixed the typos, but it still looks unreadable.

Comment: @Yuriy Faktorvich: That's not correct, the horizontal scrollbars are not dependent on the width of the browser; the space that is reserved for content on StackOverflow is fixed.  As for what I've used, I did not use anything, I formatted it by hand.  Thank you for making it somewhat more readable.

Comment: @casperOne it seems to. I had a widescreen, and when maximized I didn't see a scrollbar on his answer in Chrome. I actually like your hand done format better than mine.

Comment: @Yuriy Faktorovich: I could always change it back?

Comment: @Yuriy Faktorovich: Done, although the parenthesis around `(cc.ChildId == kid.ChildId)` is extraneous. =)

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
var childClassroomRelationships = (
    from child in children
    select {
        childid = child.ChildId,
        classrooms = (
            from classroom in classrooms
            select new {
                classroomId = classroom.ClassroomId,
                occupied = childclassrooms.Any(
                    cc => cc.ChildId == child.ChildId),
            // Since you wanted an array.
            }).ToArray()
    // Since you wanted an array.
    }).ToArray();
```

What's very important here is that a join should *not* be used here, if it was, you would get inner join semantics, which would cause children who are not in any classrooms to not show up (which it seems you *don't* want from the example you gave).

Note that this will materialize all sequences because of the calls to `ToArray`.

Also, it is slightly inefficient, in that to check the occupancy, it has to reiterate the entire `childclassroms` sequence every time.

This can be improved by "indexing" the childclassrooms map for efficient lookup, like so:

```
IDictionary<int, HashSet<int>> classroommap = (
    from mapping in childclassrooms
    group mapping.ClassroomId by mapping.ChildId into g
    select g).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => new HashSet<int>(g));
```

This will give you a map of `HashSet<int>` instances which you can look up the child in once you know the classroom.  With that, the first query becomes:

```
var childClassroomRelationships = (
    from child in children
    select {
        childid = child.ChildId,
        classrooms = (
            from classroom in classrooms
            select new {
                classroomId = classroom.ClassroomId,
                occupied = classroommap.ContainsKey(child.ChildId) &&
                    classroommap[child.ChildId].
                        Contains(classroom.ClassroomId),
            // Since you wanted an array.
            }).ToArray()
    // Since you wanted an array.
    }).ToArray();
```